# Not able to load relationships from CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I have a list of cities their latitude and longitude, their states and country which is available [`here`](http://botcognitivenlu.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/CityAssets/IndianCities.csv).

I want to a make hierarchical structure like:

```
(CITY)-[:HAS_LATITUDE]->(LATITUDE_VALUE)
(CITY)-[:HAS_LONGITUDE]->(LONGITUDE_VALUE)
(CITY)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(STATE)
(STATE)-[:LIES_IN]->(COUNTRY)
```

This is a sample of the CSV data:

```
Id,City,Latitude,Longitude,State,Country
1,Port Blair,11.67 N,92.76 E,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,India
2,Adilabad,19.68 N,78.53 E,Andhra Pradesh,India
3,Adoni,15.63 N,77.28 E,Andhra Pradesh,India
```

I am trying to use the [`LOAD_CSV`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) clause to load the data from the CSV and merging them, but I keep on getting:

```
(no changes, no records)
```

This is the query I am trying:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://botcognitivenlu.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/CityAssets/IndianCities.csv' AS line
WITH line
WHERE NOT line.Latitude IS NULL AND NOT line.Longitude IS NULL
MATCH (city: CITY { name: trim(line.City), Id: randomUUID(), type: 'CITY' })
MERGE (country: COUNTRY { name: trim(line.Country), Id: randomUUID(), type: 'COUNTRY' })
MERGE (state: STATE { name: trim(line.State), Id: randomUUID(), type: 'STATE' })-[:LIES_IN]->(country)
CREATE (latitude: LOCATION { name: trim(line.Latitude), Id: randomUUID(), type: 'LOCATION' })
CREATE (longitude: LOCATION { name: trim(line.Longitude), Id: randomUUID(), type: 'LOCATION' })
CREATE (city)-[:HAS_LONGITUDE]->(longitude)
CREATE (city)-[:HAS_LATITUDE]->(latitude)
CREATE (city)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(state)
RETURN *
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use of `randomUUID()` in `MATCH` (and `MERGE`) clause is the real issue here.

When you try to match CITY node, `randomUUID()` generates new value every time which will definitely not match with the old value of Id field. As there will be no matching CITY node with exact properties LOAD CSV will ignore skip the creating nodes/relationships.

Remove the `randomUUID()` from all the MATCH and MERGE clauses. If you want to set Id for newly created nodes in the MERGE clause use `ON CREATE SET`.

**It's not recommended to load everything in a single query, so If possible use separate queries to load latitude & longitude, states, and country.**

Comment: what do you need example for `ON CREATE SET` or separate queries?

Comment: both would be nice

Comment: Sharing a link to the official documentation for ON CREATE SET: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match

Comment: I know about ON CREATE SET, but in this context how would I seperate my queries

Comment: okay, separate queries are the optional part here. It is for the performance of the data load query. You can check why and how we can use separate queries at this blog: https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Answer (score 0):

`Here is a solution:
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:State) ASSERT s.name IS UNIQUE; 
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Country) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/IndianCities.csv" As line
WITH line WHERE line.Latitude IS NOT NULL

MERGE (c:Country {name: line.Country})
MERGE (s:State {name: line.State})
MERGE (ci:City {id: line.Id, name: line.City, latitude: line.Latitude, longitude: line.Longitude})

MERGE (c)-[:STATE]->(s)
MERGE (s)-[:CITY]-> (ci)`